# Javascript - Append array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this data

```
var game = [
  {
    'userType' : 'VIP',
    'data' : [{
      'name' : 'John'
    }]
  },
  {'userType' : 'VIP',
    'data' : [{
      'name' : 'Michelle'
    }]
  }];

var newArr = { isActive: true };
```

I've tried to do this

> game.push.apply(game[0], newArr);

And there's no `newArr` when i did the console log

[image]

Am I missing something here?
How to append `newArr` to the first array of game? (game[0])

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding properties of one object - `newArr` to another - `game[0]` and for that you can use `Object.assign()`.

```js
var game = [{
  'userType': 'VIP',
  'data': [{
    'name': 'John'
  }]
}, {
  'userType': 'VIP',
  'data': [{
    'name': 'Michelle'
  }]
}];

var newArr = {isActive: true};
Object.assign(game[0], newArr);

console.log(game)
```

Comment: thats what im looking for!!!!! deserved marked as answer, cause you're the first. Have to wait 9 mins, btw, will do it later. Thanks man